# How do I initialise a class and have access to a variable across all methods within it?

Tags: apex

I have created a Class which has a constructor with a List variable to fetch data, the reason I have placed this in the constructor is so I don't need to make multiple SOQL calls.

I have created the class below but I don't believe this works correctly as I get this error:

> classes/Notification_Utils.cls: Variable does not exist: monitoredAccounts

Code:

```
public with sharing class Notification_Utils {
    public Notification_Utils() {
        List<Account> monitoredAccounts = [SELECT Id Account];

    }

    public boolean isMonitoredAccount(Id recId)
    {
        for(APIObjectTrackingFields__c accountRec : monitoredAccounts) {
            if(accountRec.Id == recId)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can someone advise what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to read about [variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_variables.htm), but basically you need to make sure that your variable is in the correct **scope**. Scope defines which pieces of code can access the variable. As the general rule, the variable's scope is defined by the `{` and `}` that immediately surrounds the variable.

In your code, the scope of monitoredAccounts is the function:

```
public Notification_Utils() { // Start function scope
    List<Account> monitoredAccounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account];

} // End function scope
```

You can fix this by moving the variable to the **class** scope:

```
public with sharing class Notification_Utils { // Start class scope
    List<Account> monitoredAccounts;

    public Notification_Utils() {
        monitoredAccounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account];

    }

    public boolean isMonitoredAccount(Id recId)
    {
        for(APIObjectTrackingFields__c accountRec : monitoredAccounts) {
            if(accountRec.Id == recId)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variable scoped only to the method it is created in, in this case, your `Notification_Utils` constructor. By moving where you declare the variable, you can set the scope to the entire class, allowing other instance methods to use this variable.

```
public with sharing class Notification_Utils {

    public List<Account> monitoredAccounts { get; set; }

    public Notification_Utils() {
        monitoredAccounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
    }

    public boolean isMonitoredAccount(Id recId)
    {
        for(APIObjectTrackingFields__c accountRec : monitoredAccounts) {
            if(accountRec.Id == recId)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

You can read more about how variables are scoped in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm).